# how to append data in a specific div in a php while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a comment system in which I appending comments that a user does but when I append data this comes :  `[object HTMLCollection]: [object HTMLCollection]`
and I also wanna know how to append this comment on that specific post in which user have commented.

My php code :

```
$query =  "SELECT ph.ext, ph.likes,ph.desccription, ph.image_url,ph.email,ph.username,ph.uid ,ph.id,ph.avatar_path
          FROM photos as ph
          inner join followers as fol
          on fol.user_id = ph.uid
          where fol.uid = '$id'
          ORDER BY ph.image_url DESC limit 5";
$fire = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die("can not fetch data from database ".mysqli_error($con));
if (mysqli_num_rows($fire)>0) {



  while ($users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fire)) {
    $likes = $users['likes'];
    $description = $users['desccription'];
    $username = $users['username'];
    $uid = $users['uid']; 
    $pixid = $users['id'];
    $avatar_path5 = $users['avatar_path'];


    ?>


<div class="all" >
<div class="card" >
  <div class="float" >
  <div class="avatar" >
    <img src="<?php echo $avatar_path5; ?>" width="100%" class="avatar">
  </div>

      <div class="username" style="font-weight: 600; size: 14px;  text-decoration: none; color: black !important; ">
      <p style="color: black !important;"><?php echo "<div><a href='users?id=".$users['uid']."' style='color: black !important; '>
               <h3>".$users['username']."</h3>

      </div></a>"; ?></p>
</div>
</div>
   <?php
   if ($users['ext']=='mp4') {
     ?>
     <video class="videos"  controlsList="nofullscreen nodownload" style="width: 100%; height:100%;" controls autoplay="true" muted> 
 <source src="<?php echo $users['image_url']?>" type="video/mp4">

          </video>  

<?php
}else{
  ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $users['image_url']?>" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;">
  <?php }
  ?>

             <form method="POST"  action="" >
                <div class="commentdiv">
                  <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" class="id" value="<?php echo $pixid;?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username"  value="<?php echo $activeusername;?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid"  value="<?php echo $id3;?>">
          <textarea style=""  name="comment" id="comment" class="comment"  placeholder="  comment here"></textarea>
         <button type="button" style="background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #3897f0; font-weight:600;" class="submit" id="button_id">comment</button>

       </div>

          </form>
        </div>
         <div id="comments" class="comments"  data-post-id="<?php echo $pixid;?>">
            <?php



$sql = "SELECT * FROM comment where post_id='$pixid' order by time2 desc limit 3";
$results = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($results)>0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $commentid = $row['id'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];
    $string = covertHashtags($comment);
    echo "<p class='written'>";
    echo "<a href='users2?id=".$row['user_id']."' style='color:black !important;'><b>".$row['username']."</b></a>";
    echo "  ".$string;
     $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM comment where id ='$commentid' and user_id='$id' order by comment desc limit 5 ";
$results3 = mysqli_query($con,$sql3);
     if (mysqli_num_rows($results3)>0) {

      echo "<div class='dropdown'>
  <img src='ellipsis.png' class='dots'>
  <div class='dropdown-content'>
    <br><p  class='delete' data-delete=".$commentid.">delete</p>
  </div>
</div>";

    } 
    else{
      echo "";
    }

     echo "</p>";  


  }
}else{
  echo "";
}

            ?>

          </div>
      </div>
      <br><br>



    <?php } ?>
```

and my JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('click','.submit',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
   //Get values of input fields from DOM structure 
   var dataString = {
        id: $(this).parent().find("#id").val(),
        username: $(this).parent().find("#username").val(),
        uid: $(this).parent().find("#uid").val(),
         comment: $(this).parent().find("#comment").val()
    };

   $.ajax({
   url:'comments.php',  
   data:dataString,
   success:function(){
$('#comments').append('<b>'+username+'</b>: '+comment);    
   }
   });
});
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong ?
i have updated my code and added whole php code 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use ajax, and pass a json Object?

Comment: can you please write a code for it  @Sfili_81

Comment: There are no variables named `username` or `comment` defined anywhere in the code you have shown, so how do you think it makes sense to use them to append anywhere?

Comment: `$(document).on('click','.submit',function(e){` what is `.submit` here?

Comment: It seems that you are not submitting form

Comment: He is targeting the submit class on click event and then do ajax to submit comment to server.

Comment: what kind of data you are sending from `comments.php`? show the code of that file too

Comment: He is sending the dataString object @AlivetoDie

Answer (score 1):

Your username and comment variables are not created yet.

You do like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.submit',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
       var post_id = $(this).attr("data-post-id");
       //Get values of input fields from DOM structure 
       var dataString = {
            id: $(this).parent().find("#id").val(),
            username: $(this).parent().find("#username").val(),
            uid: $(this).parent().find("#uid").val(),
             comment: $(this).parent().find(".comment").val()
        };

       $.ajax({
       url:'comments.php',  
       data:dataString,
       success:function(){
    $('#comments_'+post_id).append('<b>'+$(this).parent().find("#username").val()+'</b>: '+$(this).parent().find(".comment").val()
);    
       }
       });
    });
```

Edit your php script particularly in this line, I just added the an attribute in it.:

```
`<button type="button" style="background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #3897f0; font-weight:600;" class="submit" id="button_id" data-post-id="<?php echo $pixid;?">comment</button>`
```

and this line also:

```
<div id="comments_<?php echo $pixid;?>" class="comments">
```

I also updated `$('#comments_'+post_id).append('<b>'+$(this).parent().find("#username").val()+'</b>: '+$(this).parent().find(".comment").val()`

and i added this in the js:

```
var post_id = $(this).attr("data-post-id");
```

Comment: but how should i solve the problem for showing the comment only in this post and not in every post my php code is in a while loop in which every post have a class of comments how to select this specific class only @McBern

Comment: You should add some extra html attribute while generating your php script and use jquery to look for it. Like <div `data-post-id="1"` class="comments">Post comments here</div> Jquery will look for data post id like this `var this_post = $(this).attr("data-post-id")` then inject additional comments here like this `$(this_post).append("new comments");`

Comment: nothing is happening when i added a data-post-id and used your code

Comment: You need to show us your php script and your full html structure and your js to better understand your situation. And the things that you plan to do

Answer (score 0):

I do not clearly understand what exactly it is you expect, but from what I can see in your code I suppose the following might help.

(also you should avoid the jQuery `.on` function, use  `.click` instead)

```
$('.submit', document).click(,function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
   //Get values of input fields from DOM structure 
   id = $(this).parent().find("#id").val(),
   username = $(this).parent().find("#username").val(),
   uid = $(this).parent().find("#uid").val(),
   comment = $(this).parent().find("#comment").val()
   var dataString = {
        id: id,
        username: username,
        uid: uid,
         comment: comment
   };

   $.ajax({
   url:'comments.php',  
   data:dataString,
   success:function(){
       $('#comments').append('<b>'+username+'</b>: '+comment);    
   }
   });
```